# how to implement adwhirl on iphone app?

Tags: ios4, implementation, adwhirl, ads

I need to implement adwhirl ad in my iphone app.I don't know how ı can use adwhirl.I searched but I couldn't find enough information on this topic.can anyone help me ?
https://www.adwhirl.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See AdWhirl Tutorial may be you can understand :
[Tutorial](https://adwhirl-with-iad.googlecode.com/files/AdWhirl_pro.zip)